# testdisk partition recovery

Tags: partition, data-recovery, ext4, gpt, testdisk

Looking to recover data/partition index from this disk..

```
⚡ root@jg  ~  ls /dev/disk/by-label
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 May 4 21:06 4tb1 -> ../../sde1
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root 140 May 4 21:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 160 May 4 21:06 .
⚡ root@jg  ~  fdisk -lu /dev/sde

Disk /dev/sde: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F2AA2249-27F6-49C5-AFF8-29F7623D0999

Device Start End Size Type
/dev/sde1 2048 7814037134 3.7T Microsoft basic data
```

It used to be a EXT4 but, were trying this HDD to be GPT'ed to view the files in windows. Now, after having jumped back to Linux the partition was inadvertently changed to NTFS. However, so far nothing has been formatted.

How many partition overrides have occured. Would testdisk be able to retrieve the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.

You say "the partition was ... changed to NTFS" but you don't say how.  If all that changed was the partition type flag in the partition table (whether DOS or GPT), then that flag can be changed back and all will be fine.  You can use `gparted`, `parted`, or even `fdisk` to make that kind of change.

If the partition type changed in some other way, we need to know how.  It's best to specify the utility and the commands used in that utility.